# QueryDSLPredicateExecutor Pagination and sort is very slow

Tags: hibernate, sorting, pagination, querydsl

I am using QueryDSL to fetch data from a table having millions of records. I need pagination and sorting as well. The issue is query is very slow if I add sorting with pagination. Only pagination is relatively faster.

```
QEMP qemp = QEMP.emp;
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
builder.and(qemp.homeAddress.containsIgnoreCase(homeAddress));

Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "homeAddress");
qEmpRepository.findAll(builder, new PageRequest(pageable.getPageNumber(),       Integer.valueOf(itemPerPage),sort));
```

Please note that I have like condition and sorting as well on home address.  What could be the root cause and how to optimize it.

Comment: did you set an index on column `homeAddress`?

Comment: index is already there on homeAddress.